# Google Analytics is not tracking all of our pages

Tags: google-analytics

Our website is insynchq.com. In the All Pages report under Content -> Site Content we can only see data for some our pages, like /, /getstarted, and /download. Others, like /gmail, /about, and /mobile are not shown, even if we are sure that there have been visits to them. We use a template for our pages so the scripts that are loaded for / (for example) should also be loaded for /gmail, so it doesn't seem to be a problem with the installation of the tracking code. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Should does not equal does. Did you actually *check* that the scripts are being loaded on the pages? As you currently phrase things, you just seem to be assuming the template is working properly. Even if the code exists, there might be some other error or whatever that's interfering with proper execution, for example.

Comment: The chrome extension ghostery confirms that the javascript is being loaded. There are also no errors in the console. We also have other javascripts on the pages and we can confirm that they run as well.

Answer (score 1):

We were finally able to resolve the problem. Turns out our programmer misplaced the _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); in the untracked pages.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 pages you give examples for working have a difference compared to those which don't work. In the code for the working pages (getstarted and download) there is no tracking for HitTail or Crazy Egg (and both HitTail and Crazy Egg are javascript tags to third party sites).

My guess is one of these javascript code blocks is confusing Google Analytics.

Comment: There is HitTail and Crazy Egg for / though, and it is being recorded in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to say which one of the following might be the cause:

1. The scripts that you include before google analytics tracking code, might be the cause.
2. Google specifically ask users to: *"Copy the following code, then paste it onto every page you want to track immediately before the closing  tag."* - you add JS code after google-analytics tracking code, before the closing of `</HEAD>`
3. JS code supposed to be declared as `<script type="text/javascript">` while you use `<script>`
4. From google-analytics: `If you're using PHP put the tracking  code in a file (for example, analyticstracking.php) and upload it to your site. Then add the following line to each template page immediately after the opening <body> tag: <?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>`
5. You're calling https://d2t3ff60b2tol4.cloudfront.net/c/z/orQDXd/gz/jquery.min.js is it a trusted/valid source ? personally I like to use: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
6. Are you using a [profile filter](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55494) with your SEO friendly URLs ?